# Search method with multiple Parameters

Tags: laravel

I created a search function with multiple parameters in my form view.

In my form I have:

- select box for competition
- date_field
- select box for the team 1 and another one for team 2.

I would like for example to search only with competition or only with date or only with team 1 or 2. With my actual query if I don't send all the params, I get no results.

Does someone know how to achieve that?

---

Here's the controller:

```php
public function getRencontres(Request $request){

    $compet = Compet::pluck('lb_compet' , 'id');

    $equipe = Equipe::pluck('lb_equipe' , 'id');

    $date_rencontre = $request->input('dt_rencontre');

    $search = $request->input('compet_id');

    if ($search) {
        $query = Rencontre::where(function($q) use($search , $equipe , $date_rencontre) {
            $q->where('compet_id', '=', $search)
                ->where('equipe_domicile_id' , '=' , $equipe)
                ->where('equipe_visiteur_id' , '=' , $equipe)
                ->where('dt_rencontre' , '=' , $date_rencontre);
        });
    }else {
        $query = Rencontre::select();
    }

    $rencontres = $query->orderBy('dt_rencontre', 'DESC')->paginate(10)
        ->appends(['recherche' => $search]);

    return view('rencontres/index' , compact('rencontres' , 'compet' , 'equipe'));
}
```

Comment: `Equipe::pluck('lb_equipe' , 'id')` will give you the IDs of all teams. You're making that query twice, and saving it once for the home team, and then for the other team. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i updated you are right ! but now let's assume that i put only the compet_id on my form and i run the query i get no result .

Comment: Your code still makes no sense. You should really go through it again.

Comment: what is wrong ? i would like to perform a search query on compet_id or equipe_id or dt_rencontre or all in the same time .

Comment: `Equipe::pluck('lb_equipe' , 'id')` will return a list of _all_ IDs in your table. You can't then use it in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but I think you're really looking for the [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#conditional-clauses) method on the query builder:

```php
$query = Rencontre::query();

$filters = [
    'equipe_domicile' => 'equipe_domicile_id',
    'equipe_visiteur' => 'equipe_visiteur_id',
    'dt_rencontre' => 'dt_rencontre',
    'compet_id' => 'compet_id',
];

foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
    $query->when($request->{$key}, function ($query, $value) use ($column) {
        $query->where($column, $value);
    });
}
```

Even if this is not exactly what you're after, it should get you off on the right track.

Comment: yes it's exactly what i'am looking for ! where should i put this code ?

Comment: Ok i finaly found ! with your code it's working ! thanks a lot Joseph !!